# How to place the unit in front of the number in siunitx?

Tags: siunitx

For Euro, and I assume also for other currencies, it is recommended to put the symbol "€" in front of the number, opposed to most other scientific units where the symbol goes after the number.

I can of course achieve this using a custom `\qtyeuro` command, but maybe there's a better way?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{eurosym,siunitx}
\DeclareSIUnit{\EURO}{\text{\euro}}
\newcommand{\qtyeuro}[1]{\unit{\EURO}\,\num{#1}}
\begin{document}
I want \qty{12.34}{\EURO} to look like \qtyeuro{12.34}.
\end{document}
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: It is not at all recommended to place € in front of the amount. See https://publications.europa.eu/code/en/en-370303.htm. where you see that the practice is for English, Irish, Maltese and Dutch; for all the other EU languages, the symbol should *follow* the amount.

Comment: @egreg Sure, the wiki article https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euro_sign where I looked it up says the same thing. But I'm writing in English, and its the most relevant language in science generally, so "not at all" seems a bit harsh.

Comment: It is not “recommended”. It's “mandatory”.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Currency units are *not* "scientific" units and thus frequently do not adhere to the formatting guidelines established for scientific units. E.g., it's customary in some (but not all!) currencies to always show *exactly two* decimal digits even when dealing with integer quantities of currencies; moreover, non-integer amounts of currencies should often be rounded (or truncated?) automatically to exactly 2 decimal digits.

To incorporate these practices, I would modify your proposed definition of `\qtyeuro` and add three options to the `\num` part, as shown in the following example.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{eurosym,siunitx}
\newcommand{\qtyeuro}[1]{%
    \euro\,\num[minimum-decimal-digits=2,
                round-precision = 2, 
                round-mode = places]{#1}}
\begin{document}
\euro\,12, \qtyeuro{12}, \qtyeuro{34.5678}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Obviously, one could extend the definition of `\qtyeuro` in order to deal with the formatting of *large* amounts of a currency. E.g., which thousands-separator should be employed? In addition, which decimal separator should be employed: period or comma? I suspect that national practices differ in these regards even for euro-denominated quantities.